# MVC Dynamically append img tag from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, model-view-controller

I want to add unknown number of images based on how many is there for specific user; i have used .Append function for div,labels,inputs and its work fine but when i want to append  with source its not working !
so how can i do this ?
i have tried this:

```
 `  string sc = "$('<img/>', {src=\"~/Content/themes/img2.jpg\" alt=\"\",class:'table-wrapper'}).appendTo(finalDalata);";
```

return JavaScript(sc)`

finalDalata is my Div name
so whats iam doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by `TagBuilder`

```
TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("img");
            tag.Attributes.Add("id", "myImage");
            tag.Attributes.Add("src", "/imgs/" + UserName + ".jpg");
            tag.Attributes.Add("alt", "my image");
            tag.Attributes.Add("class", "imgsClass");
```

then convert `tag` to string and pass it back to `view`

thnx

Answer (score 0):

Your appendTo code is invalid, it needs a selector, and your image attributes are not formatted properly, so it should be:

```
string sc = "$('<img/>', { src:'~/Content/themes/img2.jpg', alt:'', class:'table-wrapper'}).appendTo('#finalDalata');"
```

However, controller should return data and not control (exploits and injections comes to mind), so a better way would be to create an AppendImage function on the View side in javascript:

```
function AppendImage(attributes)
{
    $('<img/>', attributes).appendTo('#finalDalata');
}
```

Note: you should probably sanitize the attributes before to be sure.

Then return a list of attributes only:

```
var images = new List<dynamic>();
// Do this for each images
images.Add(new { src="~/Content/themes/img2.jpg", alt="", class="table-wrapper"});
return Json(images);
```

And in the ajax success you can:

```
success: function (data) {
    data.foreach( function (item) {
        AppendImage(item);
    });
}
```

Comment: i need some data from SQL DataBase and some other from another function in controller and model and base on this data to choose a photo so i really need the first solution, and i noticed the "=" sign and change it to ":" but nothing happened !!!!

Comment: There are 2 equals to change, and the appendTo needs a selector: .appendTo('#finalDalata'); Notice the '' and #.